# Kernel restarting during Tensorflow Lite model Inference (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, kernel, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use TensorFlow Lite model to make predictions for the input data. The Neural Network was trained using Keras and then was converted to TFLite standard model as following:

```
keras_file = "pruned_model.h5"
converter = lite.TocoConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

And saved it locally:

```
TFLITE_MODEL = "dts-model.tflite"
open(TFLITE_MODEL, "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Then I loaded the model into Interpreter representation, so the inference process can run on it:

```
tflite_interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=TFLITE_MODEL)

# extracted input and output details
input_details = tflite_interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = tflite_interpreter.get_output_details()

#created random sample data matching input shape
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
```

And when trying to run the following code, the notebook Kernel keeps crashing.

```
tflite_interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
```

[Kernel crash/restart screenshot](https://ibb.co/60Nk9cB)

EDIT: Here's the terminal traceback of the kernel. Before executing this code when I run the interpreter, it is initialized, and after executing the above, it restarts.

```
INFO: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
[I 09:04:00.289 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel d960c8d0-d14d-416a-bee3-3549c6a11c76 restarted
```

And here's the list of kernels for Jupyter:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
>> Available kernels:
>> python3    /home/username/anaconda3/envs/LearningML/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I am not exactly sure why is this happening.

1) Why do the kernels generally restart and what is the reason for my kernel's restart?
2) Is there any better way I can run TFLite model inference and get outputs?

Thanks!

Comment: If your kernel is running locally , Can you put the traceback displayed on terminal where notebook's server is running ?

Comment: @YashKumarAtri Yes it is running locally. I've edited to post to add that.. Please have a look!

Comment: Did you update your ubuntu (16 to 18) ? , Can you try reinstalling the jupyter and making sure that no other application is interfering with the port.

Comment: I did not update from 16 to 18 as I've fairly recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.. And how can I make sure that no other application is interfering with the port?